# Save relation between two models when creating one of them

Tags: django, django-forms

I have three (simplified) models, let's call them `Location`, `Thing` and `Where`:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
class Where(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(to = Location)
    thing = models.ForeignKey(to = Thing)
```

Then I used the generic `CreateView` to create a `Location`. But I struggle to create a view to create a `Thing`. What I want to have is a form like this:

```
class ThingForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    location = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Location.objects.all())
```

This form takes the data used to create a new `Thing`, but it also takes the date to create a new `Where`. However, I don't know how to create the new `Where`.

My view looks like this:

```
class ThingCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Thing
    form_class = ThingForm
    success_url = 'somewhere/'
```

I read that I have to override the view's `form_valid` function to do some stuff after the form data was validated:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    where = Where(location = form.location, thing = ???)
    where.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

The question is: What to put as thing? As far as I understood the documentation, the newly created `Thing` is not yet saved, thus I can't refer to it in the database's `Where` table.

How can I create a relation between `Thing` and `Location` when creating a `Thing`? Or is this the wrong approach and I need to write my own view instead of using the generic CreateView? Or even something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the records: The described construct is not possible. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#auto-incrementing-primary-keys) says:

> If a model has an AutoField — an auto-incrementing primary key — then that auto-incremented value will be calculated and saved as an attribute on your object the first time you call save() [..] There’s no way to tell what the value of an ID will be before you call save(), because that value is calculated by your database, not by Django.

As the Where table will contain the primary keys of Location and Thing, they need to be available when adding a new line to that table. So the solution is to not use the generic CreateView, but write a custom view:

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            t = Thing(name = form.cleaned_data['name'])
            t.save()
            w = Where(
                thing = t,
                location = form.cleaned_data['location'])
            w.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thing/{0}'.format(thing.id))
    else:
        form = CreateForm()

    return render(request, 'create_form.html', {'form': form})
```